# Dynamic number of forms on template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I have a form template of Class-room. There are **two fields**

```
 1. Teacher name
 2. Subject
```

There is another part of the form called students. This part will be included **multiple number of row** *(I mean suppose user can press button 'add another student' and add another student)*. **Each row includes 3 fields**

```
 1. name
 2. email
 3. phone
```

So ultimately the structure of the form will be like -

```
Teacher name: ............  Subject:................

Students:

Name:................ Email:................. Phone:..............

Name:................ Email:................. Phone:..............

Name:................ Email:................. Phone:..............

Name:................ Email:................. Phone:..............
```

Add another student

**How** can I build a single form in Django-form for this structure. A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than with a `FormSet`?

Comment: Both will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link of a **how to**

[Tutorial : Implementing Django Formsets](http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html)

And the django documentation : [Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets)